# Qual é a melhor maneira de gerar dados do meu banco para alguma planilha?

Tags: php

Tenho um banco com 40.000 dados (com uma pancada de colunas), queria gerar um relatório.

O problema é que em `.xls` demora-se demais pra gerar os dados dentro da planilha, existe alguma forma melhor de se implementar? `.csv` é mais rápido de abrir?

Answer (score -1):

Salve sua planilha com a extensão CSV. Este formato permite que os principais banco de dados importem facilmente seus dados.

Como você trabalha com PHP, seria interessante optar pelo MySQL como banco de dados.

1. Salve sua planilha com a extensão CSV.
2. Crie seu banco de dados no MySQL.
3. Faça o download do HeidiSQl, um front-end open-source muito amigável para administrar seus bancos - http://www.heidisql.com/download.php
4. Conecte o HeidiSQL ao seu servidor MySQL (localhost se for na sua máquina local, ou no IP do servidor remoto)
5. Crie seu banco de dados, crie as tabelas que irão receber os dados. O Heidi oferece ferramentas bem intuitivas para criar seu banco.
6. Com o banco dados e as tabelas criadas, clique no menu Ferramentas > Importar Dados CSV.
7. Com os dados importados, conecte seu arquivo PHP no banco de dados criado.

Outra solução é optar pelo SQL Server como banco de dados. É possível importar planilhas direto na linha de comando.

```
SELECT * INTO CADASTRO FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=c:ARQUIVO_A_SER_IMPORTADO.xls', 
'SELECT * FROM [NOME_DA_PLANILHA$]')
```

Caso este comando não funcione de imediato, faça as seguintes alterações no seu SQL Server;

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
GO
reconfigure with override
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1
GO
reconfigure with override
GO
```